# Having trouble with form requests

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I've setup two pages. 1.aspx, and 2.aspx.

on 1.aspx I have a form like so:

```
<form action="2.aspx" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" value="this works" id="mydata" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

on 2.aspx I have this code:

```
Response.Write(Request.Form("mydata"))
```

This returns nothing.

I also tried

```
Response.Write(Request.Form(0))
```

but I get "Index was out of range." Message from the server.

I know I'm probably missing something very simple, but, I can't seem to find it!

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Silly question but you do start from 1.aspx and redirect to 2.aspx by clicking submit button?

Comment: Not a silly question since I'm sure that what i'm missing is probably as simple. but yes. I do redirect using the submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having

```
<input type="hidden" value="this works" id="mydata" />
```

have

```
<input type="hidden" value="this works" name="mydata" />
```

IF you want to keep id instead of name you have to write it out differently. 
you want to use document.getElementById instead of Request.form

Answer (score 2):

ID is used for client-side access. Give your hidden field `name="mydata"` for server-side form access